# What are the restrictions to use PushKit?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My application doesn't have any VoIP features like audio/video calls. If I use VoIP notifications, will apple reject my application? Is there any such restriction to use this?

I need VoIP notification because it is guarantee that app will launch in background even if user kills the app.

Comment: no, apple will not reject your app. no restriction.

Comment: your app will not allow to release in china because they have banned voip features. so remove china country from territories.

Comment: You can launch app in background through APNS too, you need to add "mutable-content" flag into your APNS payload and service extention into your app.

Answer (score 6):

Note that Apple has introduced a restriction in iOS 13. The app will not be rejected, but will crash and may stop to receive notifications if it receives a VoIP notification and a call is not reported to CallKit. Check out the following [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118607) where one of the Apple staff members replied

> On iOS 13.0 and later, incoming Voice over IP calls must be reported when they are received and before the didReceiceIncomingPush() method finishes execution, using the CallKit framework, or the system will terminate your app.
>
> Repeatedly failing to report calls may prevent your app from receiving any more incoming call notifications.
>
> Basically, you can no longer use VoIP pushes for non VoIP messaging, and will need to use regular push notifications for those.
>
> This was announced during the WWDC session "Advances in App Background Execution" https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the pushkit framework (using the voip certicate) to send voip notifications to our devices in the same way currently we are doing with Apns (regular notifications), i mean, there is some rule or restriction for using the pushkit framework and sending only notifications without using the voip calls